# SSRS 2008R2 Grouped bar graph with aggregate line graph

Tags: bar-chart, ssrs-2008-r2, linegraph

I have a set of *n* product quantities vs dates and I want to display in category groups for the products and the series is the date as a bar graph. I then want to place an aggregated total quantity as a line graph so 1 line graph and *n* bar graphs on the same chart. The number of products coming in is dynamic.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

To ensure the number of products is dynamic you would need first set up a parameter, integer value, and default it to say maybe "5"

secondly amend your dataset to include the following in your select statement:
DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY "Product") AS "Rank"

thirdly on your graph go to series group properties, filters and input expression "RANK", OPERATOR = "<=" and VALUE = "[@ReportParameter]"